# Submitting issues to a public GitHub project anonymously

Tags: github

It looks like it is not possible to submit issues (ie bug reports and feature requests) to a public GitHub repository without logging-in to GitHub first.

Does anyone know of any way to enable or circumvent this?

Edit: I'm looking to activate this on a specific repository that I control. I'm not looking for a way to comment anonymously on other public repos.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is 'why'? Leave my public GitHub alone! :o)

Comment: Why? If you can't take at least some form of responsibility for your comments, why are you posting in the first place? Not to mention this is quite off-topic for SO.

Comment: True, but a lot of our target community is not on GitHub - how can we allow them to send requests?

Comment: @raffazizzi create a form that they can use anonymously and then take the form's contents and submit it to github automatically via a user you control. (Make sure to implement rate limiting etc)

Comment: @Daenyth interesting idea! I had just found this tool here that seems to do just that https://gitreports.com/